# Setting values in select2 initial

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I need to set default values to the select2 option select which is multiple select and ajax.

Here is the code that i have so far

```
$("#firstList").select2({
        placeholder: "Enter Pincode",
    allowClear: true,
     cache: true,
     initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var data = {id: "IN", text: "INDIA"};
        callback(data);
    },
        ajax: {
            url: "../getZipList",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                //console.log(params)
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {

                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };
                //console.log(data.it)
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page  


    })
```

When i try this

```
initSelection : function (element, callback) {
    var data = {id: "IN", text: "INDIA"};
    callback(data);
},
```

The initial values didn't set...

I also tried

```
var data = [{
      id: 'value',
      text: 'Text to display'
    }];

    var tags = $("#firstList option").each(function () {
        data.push($(this).val());

    });
```

But the initial values are not setting.

What is the problem i am doing and how can i fix it. Help pls

Comment: Can you provide a `DEMO`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/allaudeen/2ftk5c8z/305/ But due to some problems it is not working.. Can u help pls

Comment: Could you please also tell what you get with URL - `../getZipList`

Comment: Did you notice this **`select2.min.js:21 Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.`** console error?

Comment: Yeah it is showing only in fiddle , but not in my machien.. That what i said before...

Comment: Here is the one that i get in getziplist call http://s33.postimg.org/dyulxvven/new.png

Comment: What version of `select2` you are using in your machine?

Comment: Both are same right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113097/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-sulthan-a).

Comment: Hi i have posted a new question.. If possible answer it pls http://stackoverflow.com/q/37475968/5967286